# How to find the range of a function without a graph?

Tags: calculus, functions

Okay so I know how to find the domain of the function  $f(x) = \frac{3x^2}{x^2-1}$, which is $x\neq 1$ and $x\neq -1$, but I'm totally confused on how to find the range without using a graph.

Comment: Hint:  most meaningful part is the behavior near the singularities.  what happens if $x$ is slightly greater than $1$?  What if it is slightly less than $1$?

Comment: Check for horizonal and slant asymptotes, and continuity.

Comment: Making a sign chart for the function and for its derivative will be quite helpful. Those will essentially let you sketch the graph, so they furnish the same information.

Comment: Note that it is even, so you only need to consider $x\ge 0$ (and $x \neq 1$). Note that  $f(0) = 0$. If $x \in (0,1)$ the denominator is negative, and $\lim_{x \uparrow 1} f(x) = -\infty$. Hence by continuity we see that the range contains $(-\infty,0]$. Note that we can write $f(x) = { 3 \over 1-{1 \over x^2}}$, so we can see that for $x>1$, the value of $f(x) $ lies in $(3, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $$y=\frac{3x^2}{x^2-1}$$ and rearrange to get $$(y-3)x^2-y=0$$ 
This quadratic has real roots provided $b^2-4ac\geq 0$ which translates as $$y(y-3)\geq 0$$
Noting that $y=3$ is the horizontal asymptote, the solution set, i.e.the range, is $$y\leq 0, y>3$$

Answer (score 1):

Write the function as 
$$f(x)=\frac{3x^2-3+3}{x^2-1}=3+\frac3{x^2-1}$$
As $f$ is even, we may suppose $x\ge 0,\enspace x\ne q 1$.

Now the range of $x^2-1$ is $[-1,+\infty)$ and for $f(x)$, the value $x^2=1$ is excluded, hence the range of $\;\dfrac3{x^2-1}$ is $(-\infty,-3] $ for $x\in [0,1)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ for $x>1$.

Hence the range of $f(x)=3+\dfrac3{x^2-1}$ is $\;(-\infty,0]\cup (3,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

find for what values of $k$ the equation $k=\dfrac{3x^2}{x^2-1}$ has real solutions.

For $ x\ne \pm 1$ you have $ x^2= \dfrac{k}{k-3}$ so this fraction must be not negative: $\dfrac{k}{k-3}\ge 0$. The solution is the range.